# How to make left margin smaller on PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I notice that there's a lot of space between the line numbers and where my code begins (in the image, the space between "1" and "import"). Is there a way to make this space smaller?

[image]

I'm using IdeaVIM with `relativenumbers` and `numbers` turned on, but I know other people without IdeaVIM that have this issue.